# How to pass Internationalization Locale in nextjs14 app router to deep nested server-side component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization

I have created a new nextjs14 project and setup Internationalization exactly as it i mentioned in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization).

***Now I want to know the most elegant way to access the current language setting to render contents conditionaly in deep-nested server-side components***

##### This is the RootLayout Component

```
import './globals.css';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Marhey } from 'next/font/google';
import { Locale, getDictionary } from './dictionaries';
import Header from '@/components/layout/Header';
import { LocalContext } from "@/context/locale";

const marhey = Marhey({ subsets: ['arabic'] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ lang: 'en' }, { lang: 'ar' }];
}

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { lang: Locale };
}

const RootLayout: React.FC<Props> = async ({ children, params: { lang } }) => {
  const dict = await getDictionary(lang);

  return (
    <LocalContext dict={dict} lang={lang}>
      <html lang={lang} dir={lang === 'en' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'}>
        <body className={`${marhey.className} bg-[#CAEEED]`}>
          <Header dict={dict} lang={lang} />
          <main className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 py-2 sm:py-6">
            {children}
          </main>
          <footer className='m-8'></footer>
        </body>
      </html>
    </LocalContext>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;
```

##### Here I want to use the current locale to render text conditionaly based on language

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Book } from '@prisma/client';

interface Props {
  book: Book;
}

const BookCard: React.FC<Props> = ({ book }) => {
  
  return (
    <div
      key={book.id}
      className='group relative flex flex-col overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white shadow-md hover:cursor-pointer'
    >
      <div className='group-hover:opacity-75'>
        <Image
          src={`/en/images/cover/${book.id}_${book.title_en}.jpg`}
          alt={book.title_en}
          width={128}
          height={193}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='p-2 text-center'>
        <h3 className='text-sm font-medium text-gray-900'>
          <Link href={'#'}>
            <span aria-hidden='true' className='absolute inset-0' />
            {book.title_en}
          </Link>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookCard;
```